# To nest or not to nest a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have been playing around with Rails again for the last couple of days.

I'm unsure if I should nest a resource or not, and how to determine it.

Let's pretend I have an application where users can sign up and make a todo list. They can choose to make these lists public or private.

Where I'm running into trouble is if I should nest the lists under the user resource:

If I do that, I end up with something like:

`/users/:id/lists`
`/users/:id/lists/:list_id`

But what if I want to say, have a view with all public lists under `/lists`? That would interfere with the restful-ness of the routes, no?

I could not nest the lists and have separate routes for users and lists, but then I run into trouble again, in my mind at least.

`/users/:id # some profile page`
`/lists # should this link to all lists or all the current user's lists?`

But then, if I want to show a specific user's lists, I don't know what my route would be.

Is there a way to combine this somehow? Nest the lists under the user resource, but still have the `/lists` lists_path? Or would that just be a custom named route?

I'm interested in how people who are more proficient than me in Rails would tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both a nested and non-nested lists.

`resources :lists` will create all of the restful routes.

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists
end
```

will then create all of the nested routes and associated helpers. I wouldn't use nested routes in this scenario, because your controller is going to be a shitshow.

Nested routes (let's say users/7/lists) by default routes to `ListsController#index`, but you also have /lists that is going to `ListsController#index`. So you can add some logic to your controller:

```
ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:user_id].present?
      # I'm in a user_list
    else
      # I'm in a public list
    end
  end
end
```

Ugh.

Okay how about a before_filter?

```
ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :unjankify_nested_routes

  private      

  def unjankify_nested_routes
    if params[:user_id].present?
      # I'm in a user_list
      render "users_#{@action}"
    else
      # I'm in a public list
    end
  end
end
```

Now we can basically scope the controller methods by saying users_show, users_index etc. But what is that @action variable? We need to capture that.

```
class ApplicationController     
  def process_action(name, *args)
    @action_name = name
    super rescue false #no super in tests
  end
end
```

We just overrode an internal Rails method to capture the action name. That's fun, but kind of seems like we're doing something wrong.

### The Right Way (tm)

There is no 'right way' but [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) are a good option

```
scope 'privates' do
  resources :lists
end
```

Now we can have a `Privates::ListsController` in `app/controllers/privates/lists_controller`. you can add the user_id in the query params, or nest routes under the scope:

```
scope 'privates' do
  resources :users do  
    resources :lists
  end
end
```